# Highmaps - colorAxis[0].update does not update country colors

Tags: highcharts

Im creating a mapchart with highcharts but Im having a hard time matching the colors of the countries with the coloraxis.

This is an example image of how it looks:

[image]
This is part of a function that creates the chart :

```
  function createChart() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Map({
      colorAxis: {
        maxColor: '#7b9b00',
        minColor: '#d7e241',
        type: 'linear',
        allowDecimals: false,
        marker: {
          color: 'black'
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return this.value;
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        name: 'countries',
        borderColor: 'black',
        showInLegend: false,
        borderWidth: 0.2,
        states: {
          hover: {
            borderWidth: 1
          }
        }
      }]
    });
  }
```

I then wait for an an API-call to complete, and then update the chart with this code:

```
  function updateSeries(newData) {
    chart.colorAxis[0].update({
      min: getMin(newData),  //Value is 556910
      max: getMax(newData) // Value is 353573853
    }, true);

    chart.addSeries({
      data: newData,
      title: 'Performance by Country',
      mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
      joinBy: ['hc-key', 'country'],
      name: 'countries',
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 0.2,
      states: {
        hover: {
          borderWidth: 1,
          color: '#7b9b00'
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

The data that i pass in have the following structure:
[image]

Are here any obvious errors with my code?

Comment: Do you have value parameter specified in your points? I think that adding this parameter may help you with your issue.

Comment: This helped, thanks!